# Firebase webapp with GoDaddy custom Domain does not show HTTPS

Tags: firebase, ssl, https, hosting, firebase-hosting

I added a custom domain from GoDaddy to my firebase hosted application. The application is loading fine but the URL shows HTTP instead of HTTPS. when I type HTTPS manually, the page does not load. How can I enable HTTPS on this webapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for SSL certificate provisioning. After Firebase verify domain ownership, they provision an SSL certificate for your domain and deploy it across their global CDN within 24 hours after you point your DNS A records to Firebase Hosting.

Your domain will be listed as one of the Subject Alternative Names (SAN) in the FirebaseApp SSL certificate. You can view this certificate using the browser's security tools. **While the domain is provisioning, you might see an invalid certificate that does not include your domain name. This is a normal part of the process and will resolve after your domain's certificate is available.**

Have a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#ssl-provisioning) official documentation for more details.

Comment: That means there is nothing to do from the GoDaddy side to enable SSL right?

Comment: Yeah, as per the documentation.